# "Could not load symbol clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties" after upgrading Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is the error I get when upgrading a Unity project to a new version after mistakenly building it in an old version originally:

> Could not load symbol clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties : The specified procedure could not be found.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem with OpenCL:  https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/could-not-load-symbol-clcreatecommandqueuewithproperties-error-when-opening-project

> Reproduction steps:
>
> 1. Open new Unity project
> 2. Observe Console window
>
> Expected result: No errors Actual result:
> "clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties" error
>
> Observed on Windows and can potentially happen on Linux too.
>
> Requires an OpenCL 1.2 device to reproduce.
>
> Reproducible with: 2020.1.0f1 Could not test with: 2018.4.26f1,
> 2019.4.8f1, 2020.1.2f1, 2020.2.0a20 (error only appears on user's end)

Resolution Notes:

> Resolution Note (fix version 2021.1):
>
> Fixed in 2021.1.0a1

> Resolution Note (fix version 2020.2):
>
> Fixed in 2020.2.0b12

> Resolution Note (fix version 2020.1):
>
> Fixed in 2020.1.14f1

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your drivers, update OpenCL, reinstall from official website, reinstall your graphic cards, update drivers and it will solve the problem.